# Pycord Slash commands, How do you set guild_ids too all guilds bot is in

Tags: python, discord, pycord

In `Pycord` when creating a slash command you need to tell it what servers it can be used in. You do this by adding a argument called `guild_ids`.

But how would I put a list of guild ids for all the servers my bot is in? I've tried multiple methods but unless I set the `guild_ids` manually it won't let other servers use them.

It would also have to update every few seconds in case someone invites it too a new server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a thing called "global slash commands". If you check the [Pycord docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#slashcommand) for the slash command, you'll find that the `guild_ids` parameter is optional, i.e. you can simply omit the `guild_ids` parameter. If no guild ids are provided, the command will be created globally and be available on every server the bot is in (provided the bot has been granted the `applications.commands` scope on invite). Note that it may take [up to an hour](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#making-a-global-command) before a global slash command is synchronized to all servers

Comment: Ah, thank you. I tried this but didn't realize I had to wait for an hour.

Comment: Please note this will also enable the commands in DMs too.